# How do you compute each row of foreach double value to compute into a SINGLE value?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, foreach, logic

Right now I have this logic behind my code:

```
INSERT INTO PAYMENT (amount, appointmentID) VALUES
(@amount1, @app1),
(@amount2, @app2),
(@amount3, @app3),
...
```

Let's say @amount1 is 10, @amount2 is 15, @amount3 is 20

How do i compute the TOTAL value of amount1, amount2, amount 3, etc. and submit it into the database as a total value of 45 in this manner: (@amount1, @app1)?  how do I approach this kind of logic?

This is what I have for my button click code:

```
string cMedication = string.Empty;
string cQuantity = string.Empty;
string cAppointment = string.Empty;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataPrescription.Rows)
{
    cMedication = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    cQuantity = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    cAppointment = txtAppointmentID.Text;

    if (cAppointment == "NO APPOINTMENT HAS BEEN MADE")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please make an appointment first at the Nurse counter", "WARNING");
    }
    else
    {
        this.calculateTotal(cMedication, cQuantity, cAppointment);
    }
}
```

and this is my calculateTotal function:

```
private void calculateTotal(string cMedication, string cQuantity, string cAppointment)
{
    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

    string insertPayment = "INSERT INTO PAYMENT (amount, appointmentID) " +
        "VALUES (@insertAmount, @insertAppointment)";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdPayment = new SqlCommand(insertPayment, connection))
        {
            string strPrice = "SELECT medicationPrice FROM MEDICATION WHERE medicationName= @getName";
            SqlCommand cmdPrice = new SqlCommand(strPrice, con);
            cmdPrice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getName", cMedication);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader readPrice = cmdPrice.ExecuteReader();
            if (readPrice.Read())
            {
                string getPrice = readPrice["medicationPrice"].ToString();
                double doublePrice = Convert.ToDouble(getPrice);
                double doubleQuantity = Convert.ToDouble(cQuantity);

                double result = doublePrice * doubleQuantity;

                string answer = result.ToString();
                cmdPayment.Parameters.AddWithValue("@insertAmount", answer);
            }

            readPrice.Close();
            con.Close();

            cmdPayment.Parameters.AddWithValue("@insertAppointment", txtAppointmentID.Text);

            connection.Open();
            cmdPayment.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to sum everything up? I don't see any code for summing the amount1 amount2 amount3 params up. 
Do you want it to happen in the database or in your code? I.E do you need to present it to someone in a UI or is it enough that you have it in the database?

Comment: That's because I don't know how to approach that method, hence this question.  This just a simple INSERT to a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to avoid too many roundtrips to the database. A couple select-insert statements inside a loop is not considered a best practice.

I'd try to use a `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO PAYMENT (amount, appointmentID) 
SELECT price * quantity, appointmentID FROM MEDICATION
INNER JOIN APPOINTMENT
ON "whatever_matches_medications_and_appointments"
```